# Selecting the text written in double quotes in textbox.. windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

i am sorry bu i am new to c# and need to learn a lot :(
can u people help me by telling how can i select the text written in quotes in richtextbox?
like if i writ in richtextbox on debugging the program

```
        cout<<"HELLO WORLD"; 
        HELLO WORLD= new array
```

the , HELLO WORLD should be stored to a new array/string

Comment: cout ? i think you're confusing c++ with c#

Comment: actually i am talking about writing any text in textbox while program has debugged or is in running condition... if i write ...............i love "ME"...... ME should be stored to a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are indeed working with c# (instead of c++, which i think you are) you can do the following:

```
  string  input = TextBox1.Text; //<--- replace Textbox1 with whatever you called your textbox
  string[] txtWithNoQuotes = input.Split('"');
  string noQuotes = txtWithNoQuotes[1]; // <-- this will give you Hello world, without the quotes
```

edit: think i got the question a little wrong, if you just want the text someone entered in a textbox, simply do

```
string input  = NameOfYourTextbox.Text;
```

Comment: no u got the question right... i actually needed the text written inside quoes... ur noQuotes worked for me... thank you really really very much :)

Comment: no problem, altho my way is only 1 way you can do it, you can use the other answers aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the name of your RichTextBox is RichTextBox1; then the following sets the value in the textbox (you should write this to the code behind file; if your form is named as Form1, then you should write this into Form1.cs):

```
string s = RichTextBox1.Text;
```

Comment: no no no no 
i am jus asking if i write anything in richtextbox on debugging the program inside double quotes, it gets saved to a string.... as i have to show such strings in a listbox

Answer (score 0):

To select quoted text inside `RichTextBox1` you need something like this:

```
string s = RichTextBox1.Text;
int f = s.IndexOf('"'), l = s.LastIndexOf('"');
if(f != l)
{
  RichTextBox1.Select(s, l - s + 1);
}
```